# get list from line-separated output

Tags: list, zsh

I want to get a ZSH list from a line-separated output. In my case, from the following command:

```
ssh myhost ls /Applications
```

I tried `$(ssh myhost ls /Applications)` but that doesn't work (it splits also at spaces).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`lines=("${(@f)$(ssh myhost ls /Applications)}")`

Answer (score 0):

```
${(ps.\n.)"$(ssh myhost ls /Applications)"}
```

Answer (score 0):

`myarray=(${(f)"$(ssh myhost ls /Applications)"});`

Comment: Correct in this case, but this will remove all empty lines, which is not always desirable for different commands' output.